# Any particular vacuum policy to increase performance using Drupal with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, drupal, vacuum

I'm running Drupal 7 with PostgreSQL as a Q&A (with a lot of nodes inserts/updates and several contrib modules). Do you, dba admins, recommand any particular pgsql vacuum policy on particular default tables ?

Comment: Your question might get better answers over on [our DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) -- I can move it there if you would like...

Answer (score 0):

Any recent version of Postgres will have an autovacuum process. Let the autovacuum do its work - It is very good at its job, and will run in such a way as to not interfere with normal use of the database.

If you make a huge number of changes you may want to run a `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the whole database.
If you did a lot of deleting you may opt for a `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` to compact the tables, but note that this will lock the tables while it compacts them -- Do not run it on a production system of any real size without a maintenance window.

You can read more about tuning autovacuum (and times when you might need/want to manually VACUUM your database) in [the Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/routine-vacuuming.html).